# Expanding boot partition for Ubuntu MATE

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu, partition

How do I expand the /boot_ub (Ubuntu MATE) partition? I want to upgrade to 20.04 to get some support for MATE but I can't upgrade because the partition is almost full. I tried to remove old kernel modules but there aren't any to remove.

[image: upgrade scrot]

I am aware that Xenial already reached the end of it's life April of last year, but I want to upgrade so I can get some damn support for my pi. I have considered flashing another SD card with it, but I don't know how to transfer everything over.

I have shrunk another partition and freed about 112MB. How can I expand this partition with the unallocated space (empty space)? I installed gparted but it only shrinks, not expands.

Using PINN, not NOOBS.

Comment: More for the Linux board than the pi.  Would partitioning a new SD card, copying file by file and change the boot / fstab entries work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known problem. The "solution" is to upgrade using apt from the command line.

You can't upgrade versions. If you try it will try to install a conventional boot and break your system.

Comment: I upgraded all packages and everything is up-to-date.
Can I flash a newer version of Ubuntu to another microSD card and boot it from that? Should I install Bionic or Focal?

Comment: @Arbiter If you are asking for an opinion, neither. Since Canonical stopped using Foundation firmware Ubuntu performs poorly on the Pi. The Server works OK, but the only officially supported Desktop only runs on a 8GB Pi and is missing many of the features in Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Anyways, I found a workaround. I got my other sd card and flashed it with MATE 18. Then upgraded to 20.04. Works fine, no problems.